# strange about the output precision of the function "printf"

Tags: c, printf

```
    printf("%.2lf\n",odd);                        //(1)
    printf("%.2lf\n",37.975);                     //(2)
    printf("%.2lf\n",(odd*0.65 -1)*2);            //(3)
    printf("%.3lf\n",(odd*0.65 -1)*2);            //(4)
```

Below is the output:

30.75

37.98

37.97

37.975

Why the output of expression(3) is not 37.98 ?

I use g++.

Comment: Probably because that `0.65` is actually slightly less than `0.65`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to floating point rounding errors. The result of `(odd * 0.65 - 1) * 2` is likely `37.97499999999999` or something close to (but less than) `37.975`. By the usual rounding rules, this is rounded down to `37.97` in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Since I get a different result with `odd` set to 37.975, the reason is most likely that `odd` is *slightly less* than 30.75 in your calculation (you're not showing it un-rounded in your question) which makes the calculation result in a number slightly less than 37.975.

Answer (score 1):

Computer (binary) floating point can't represent decimal numbers precisely, just like decimal floating point can't represent some fractions.  For example 1/9 = .11111111111....  Display more digits of precision, and you'll see what happened.

Since you didn't provide the value of `odd`, I chose one that gave the same result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double odd = 30.7499;
    printf("%.2lf\n",odd);                        //(1)
    printf("%.2lf\n",37.975);                     //(2)
    printf("%.2lf\n",(odd*0.65 -1)*2);            //(3)
    printf("%.3lf\n",(odd*0.65 -1)*2);            //(4)
    printf("%.20lf\n",odd);                        //(1)
    printf("%.20lf\n",37.975);                     //(2)
    printf("%.20lf\n",(odd*0.65 -1)*2);            //(3)
    printf("%.20lf\n",(odd*0.65 -1)*2);            //(4)
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
30.75
37.98
37.97
37.975
30.74990000000000000000
37.97500000000000100000
37.97487000000000300000
37.97487000000000300000
```